# Is this series convergent or divergent? $\frac{n}{1+e^{-n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't know what to do. I was thinking of root test but I get stuck whenever I do it. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a primer on how to type in MathJax and $\LaTeX$ to make your mathematical expressions easier to read.  At the moment it is difficult to tell exactly what you mean.  Perhaps $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{1+e^{-n}}$?  If that is the case, then what can you say about the behavior of the end terms?  I.e. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{1+e^{-n}}=?$

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to the website and didn't know how to do that :P

Answer (score 1):

Hint: apply the divergence/trivial test.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}$ be an infinite series. If $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}=L$$ then $$a_{n} \rightarrow 0 
$$ as $$ n \rightarrow \infty  $$.

Look at the contrapositive $ a_{n} \nrightarrow \infty$ then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}\neq L$

Test your series

Answer (score -1):

Just apply the limit test$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{1 + e^{-n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{1 + \frac{1}{e^n}}= \frac{\infty}{1 + \frac{1}{e^\infty}} = \frac{\infty}{1 + 0} = \infty$$

and so since the limit is not equal zero then the series is said to diverge

check this link also

> http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LimitTest.html

Comment: Writing things like $\;\frac\infty1\;,\;\;e^\infty\;$ can be seen both as risky and unduely informal. Some mathematicians I know would as once make the grading smaller for this.